# Add multiple css rectangles together

Tags: css

So I have 3 rectangles in my css file

```
#background .icicle#ice1 {
    left: 24%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 8%;
}

#background .icicle#ice2 {
    left: 26%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 16%;
}

#background .icicle#ice3 {
    left: 28%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 4%;
}
```

And I call them like so

```
    <div id="background">
        <div class="icicle" id="ice1"></div>
        <div class="icicle" id="ice2"></div>
        <div class="icicle" id="ice3"></div>
    </div>
```

I'd like to know how to add the ice1,2,3 together because if I were to put them together, the last rectangle would replace the previous one.

```
#background .icicle#ice1 {
    left: 24%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 8%;

    left: 26%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 16%;

    /* This one would only be displayed */
    left: 28%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 4%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Could you explain what you exactly mean?

Comment: So you need a big rectangle instead of 3 separate ones?

Comment: Did you set position:relative on the wrapper div and position:absolute on the .icicle class?

Comment: @HashemQolami: I have 3 rectangles, I want to be able to call them all at once, instead of seperately

Comment: @Danield: yes to both

Comment: @techfoobar: no, i just want to call the 3 rectangles at once, they make a squarish icicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group those three small pieces of icicles into one like these:

```
<div id="background">

    <!-- Each Icicle --->
    <div class="icicle" id="ice1">
        <!-- Pieces that make up each icicle -->
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

and position each icicle using the id's

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/KJKLV/

Comment: Is there anything you suggest doing?

Comment: Well its for a github page i was playing around with so here's the link to the actual page if you want to look at it http://exikle.github.io/

Comment: I've just done one set of icicles, was just playing with html to learn it

Comment: yes exactly, so that instead of calling each part individually, i can call them together. I wanted to be able to do this to create different sets of icicles and call them with one line

Comment: Next time, do not absolutely-position each piece of icicle to the page or wrapper, but group them by placing the smaller pieces into a div. In the example fiddle I posted, each piece of icicle is now a span, and now you can copy the structure of each icicle, and only set the position (left, top) of the cloned icicle.